# How to solve this mind boggling puzzle

Tags: cipher, pattern

[image]

I found this puzzled unattributed in one of my Facebook groups. I've been trying solve this puzzle for 2 hours, but I still no idea at all. I really need help. Any guess would really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Questions from other sources should be properly attributed - with an exact description of where they come from, and a link if possible. Once you edit those into your question, it can be reopened.

Comment: The original source can be find using a Google image search.  It's an arabic, and the premise is that it's a murder mystery and this tells you who "did it".  (I also found an image of the solution..)

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by another commenter @greenturtle3141 it's possible to reverse google search this image to find the source at https://puzzle-for-geniuses.blogspot.com/2018/12/askseven-puzzle.html
The solution is found nearby at http://www7.0zz0.com/2018/12/12/13/172175737.jpg

It's my first time posting so I'm not sure of answer conventions so I've enclosed it within spoiler tags.

> The vertical text is "must ask seven", which might be an arabic pun on 'ask' which I'm not aware of, but in any case we are supposed to begin from the red letter A and move clockwise 7 positions each time. This sort of circular indexing will obtain the phrase "ADD THE NUMBER". This can be performed for the circle on the right beginning from T to obtain "TO THE SIDES OF". This is concatenated together with the phrase "THE LETTER" so we are instructed to "ADD THE NUMBER TO THE SIDES OF THE LETTER".

> M, U, S, T, A, K, E, V, N biject to 4,3,3,2,3,3,4,2,3 respectively based on the number of lines needed to draw each letter (which explains the weird way U and S are drawn) (credit to @DeNick). Add the numbers together, take mod 26 and index to the alphabet to get GARDNER DID IT.

> M: 4 + 03 = 7  = G 
>  U: 3 + 24 = 27 = A 
>  S: 3 + 15 = 18 = R 
>  T: 2 + 02 = 4  = D 
>  A: 3 + 11 = 14 = N 
>  S: 3 + 02 = 5  = E 
>  K: 3 + 15 = 18 = R 
>  S: 3 + 01 = 4  = D 
>  E: 4 + 05 = 9  = I 
>  V: 2 + 02 = 4  = D 
>  E: 4 + 05 = 9  = I 
>  N: 3 + 17 = 20 = T

Comment: I suspect the numbers come from rot13(gur ahzore bs yvarf hfrq gb qenj gur yrggre).

Comment: I see, that makes sense! I'll add it to the solution, thanks a lot!